# If $P(X \geq a) = 1 - \frac{1}{4}a^2$, $0 \leq a \leq 2$, then what is the expectation of $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose for a random variable $X$ it is given $P(X \ge a)=1-\frac{1}{4}a^2$, for $0\le a\le 2$. what is the expectation of $X$?

**Correct answer**: $\frac{4}{3}$

> I have difficulty solving the problem with the above information, all I know is the formula for calculating expectation for continuous random variable is $E[X]=\int_a^b x \, f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$ so I tried to put that in action but I missed $x$ and $f(x)$, I assumed that those are $a$ and $P(X\ge a)$ but I know I am lost here. I want to really understand the problem and solve it.

Comment: f is the density function. You can deduce it form the distribution function $F$. $x$ is... the integration variable!

Comment: how you mean exactly, i dont know what type of distribution it is to deduce.

Comment: The distribution function is **by definition** $F(x)=P(X\le x)$.

Comment: so $F(x)$ in this case is $1-P(X \leq a)=1-1-\frac{1}{4} a^2$ , if I am correct and then $f(x)$ would be the the differentiation of $F$ so $f(a)=\frac{-2}{4}a$ , now $\int_0^2 \! a\frac{-2}{4}a  \, \mathrm{d}a$ will give me $\frac{-4}{3}$ , seems legit but still a minus:(, am i making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Is $1-(1-{\frac14 a^2})$.

Comment: yes sir , Im so boring. thx

Comment: Correction to my previous post: $F(x)$ in this case is $1−P(X\ge a)=1−(1−\frac{1}{4}a^2)$

Answer (score 1):

A quicker method is to note that for a positive random variable $X$, $EX = \int P(X\geq x)\,dx$. In your case, $\int_0^2 (1-\frac{a^2}{4})\,da = \frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: It's actually $\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>x)\mathsf dx$. Although for a continuous random variable, $\mathbb P(X=x)$ is zero for all $x$, so in this case it is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\mathbb P(X\in [0,2])=1$ and if $a\in[0,2]$ then $\mathbb P(X\lt a)=\frac{a^2}4$, from which we deduce the cumulative distribution function. A density is given by $f(t):=\frac t2\chi_{[0,2]}(t)$, from which we can compute easily the expectation.